# Can't see anything I type except on internet, can't download anything, can't even open software center.

Tags: upgrade, software-center, sudo, dpkg

If I do anything with `sudo` terminal says:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

This all started after i canceled the 11 upgrade during the download process

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal, or press Ctrl-Alt-F1 (press Ctrl-Alt-F7 to get back into XWindows), then type in:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If you have further problems, then you may wish to start a new question.